# I want to check if an element exist in an array

Tags: powershell

I want to check if a element exist in an array.

```
$data = "100400296 676100 582"
$i = "18320-my-turn-582"
if ($data -like $i) { Write-Host "Exist" }
else { Write-Host "Didn't exist" }
```

This example doesn't work like I want it. `$i` contains 582, so I want it to be `Exist` in result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string `"18320-my-turn-582"` doesn't exist in `$data`, even though both strings contain the substring `582`.

PowerShell treats your strings as a whole, and `18320-my-turn-582` is not present in `100400296 676100 582`. To work around this you can:

**Use Regex:**

```
$i -match '\d+$'
$data -match $Matches[0]
```

**Split the `$i` at hyphens so you will have:**

```
$i = $i -split '-'
# turns $i into a array with the elements:
# 18320
# my
# turn
# 582

$data -match $i[-1]
# Output: 100400296 676100 582
```

Check out [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) to understand the differences between `-Contains`, `-Match` and `-Like` operators.

Comment: Thank You very much, will read that link to, I am prettty new to use Powershell